# @Autowired not working when using spring-security (neo4j as database)

Tags: spring, spring-security, autowired

I forked an [example-spring-data-neo4j](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-cineasts) project, and build my own 'StigMod' project from it.

Everything works fine, until I tried to change the controller-service-repository structure of this project.

My `Controller -> Service -> Repository` structure.

```
@Controller
public class StigModController {

    ...

    @Autowired
    StigmodUserDetailsService stigmodUserDetailsService;

    ...
}

@Service
public class StigmodUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    ...

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    ...
}

public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {

    User findByMail(String mail);
}
```

Structure in the [example](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-cineasts):

```
@Controller
public class AuthController {

    ...

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    ...
}

public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User>, CineastsUserDetailsService {

    User findByLogin(String login);

}

@Service
public class CineastsUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

}

public class UserRepositoryImpl implements CineastsUserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

}
```

**After my refactoring, a problem popped out:**

**The `StigmodUserDetailsService` class is annotated with `@Service`. Component scan is enabled in package `net.stigmod`, and my IDE actually could recognize all the `@Autowire` dependencies in all files.
However, the autowired field `stigmodUserDetailsService` in `StigModController.java` could not be initialized during deployment.**

I tried several methods proposed by people in some similar questions, but they did not work. I guess there is soming wrong with the spring-security dymamic object feature, but I am not sure. 
I posted most of the related complete codes below. Hope someone could help me out. Thank you so much!

@@@ ERROR in Tomcat Localhost Log during deployment @@@

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stigModController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: net.stigmod.service.StigmodUserDetailsService net.stigmod.controller.StigModController.stigmodUserDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.stigmod.service.StigmodUserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: net.stigmod.service.StigmodUserDetailsService net.stigmod.controller.StigModController.stigmodUserDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.stigmod.service.StigmodUserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.stigmod.service.StigmodUserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 58 more
```

@@@ web.xml @@@

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>StigMod</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StigMod</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

@@@ applicationContext.xml @@@

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:spring-configured/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.stigmod">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"/>

</beans>
```

@@@ applicationContext-security.xml @@@

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.stigmod">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>
    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled">
    </security:global-method-security>

    <security:http> <!-- use-expressions="true" -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/about" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/signin*" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/signup*" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/signin"
                             authentication-failure-url="/signin?login_error=true"
                             default-target-url="/user"
                             login-processing-url="/signin"
                             username-parameter="mail"
                             password-parameter="password"/>
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/denied" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="stigmodUserDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder hash="md5">
                <security:salt-source system-wide="xxxxxx"/>
            </security:password-encoder>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

@@@ StigMod-servelet.xml @@@

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.stigmod.controller"/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/velocity.properties"/>
        <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/velocity/"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="prefix" value=""/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".vm"/>
        <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

@@@ Application.java @@@

```
package net.stigmod;

import net.stigmod.util.config.Config;
import net.stigmod.util.config.ConfigLoader;
import net.stigmod.util.config.Neo4j;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.server.Neo4jServer;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.server.RemoteServer;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("net.stigmod.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("net.stigmod")
public class Application extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    // Common settings
    private Config config = ConfigLoader.load();
    private Neo4j neo4j = config.getNeo4j();
    private String host = neo4j.getHost();
    private String port = neo4j.getPort();
    private String username = neo4j.getUsername();
    private String password = neo4j.getPassword();

    @Override
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory("net.stigmod.domain");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
        return new RemoteServer("http://" + host + ":" + port, username, password);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Session getSession() throws Exception {
        return super.getSession();
    }
}
```

@@@ StigModController.java @@@

```
package net.stigmod.controller;

import net.stigmod.domain.node.User;
import net.stigmod.service.StigmodUserDetailsService;
import net.stigmod.util.config.Config;
import net.stigmod.util.config.ConfigLoader;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Controller
public class StigModController {

    // Common settings
    private Config config = ConfigLoader.load();
    private String host = config.getHost();
    private String port = config.getPort();

    @Autowired
    StigmodUserDetailsService stigmodUserDetailsService;

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    // front page
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("host", host);
        model.addAttribute("port", port);
        model.addAttribute("title", "index");
        return "index";
    }

    // about this web app
    @RequestMapping(value="/about", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String about(ModelMap model) {
        final User user = stigmodUserDetailsService.getUserFromSession();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("host", host);
        model.addAttribute("port", port);
        model.addAttribute("title", "about");
        return "about";
    }

    // sign up page GET
    @RequestMapping(value="/signup", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String reg(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        model.addAttribute("host", host);
        model.addAttribute("port", port);
        model.addAttribute("title", "Sign Up");

        // CSRF token
        CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
        if (csrfToken != null) {
            model.addAttribute("_csrf", csrfToken);
        }

        return "signup";
    }

    // sign up page POST
    @RequestMapping(value="/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String regPost(
            @RequestParam(value = "mail") String mail,
            @RequestParam(value = "password") String password,
            @RequestParam(value = "password-repeat") String passwordRepeat,
            ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            stigmodUserDetailsService.register(mail, password, passwordRepeat);
            return "redirect:/user";
        } catch(Exception e) {
            model.addAttribute("host", host);
            model.addAttribute("port", port);
            model.addAttribute("title", "Sign Up");
            // CSRF token
            CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
            if (csrfToken != null) {
                model.addAttribute("_csrf", csrfToken);
            }

            model.addAttribute("mail", mail);
            model.addAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
            return "signup";
        }
    }

    // sign in page GET  (POST route is taken care of by Spring-Security)
    @RequestMapping(value="/signin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        model.addAttribute("host", host);
        model.addAttribute("port", port);
        model.addAttribute("title", "Sign In");

        // CSRF token
        CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
        if (csrfToken != null) {
            model.addAttribute("_csrf", csrfToken);
        }

        return "signin";
    }

    // sign out
    @RequestMapping(value="/signout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null){
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
        }
        return "redirect:/signin";
    }

    // Denied page GET
    @RequestMapping(value="/denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String reg(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("host", host);
        model.addAttribute("port", port);
        model.addAttribute("title", "Denied");

        return "denied";
    }
}
```

@@@ UserRepository.java @@@

```
package net.stigmod.repository.node;

import net.stigmod.domain.node.User;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {
    User findByMail(String mail);
}
```

@@@ StigmodUserDetails.java @@@

```
package net.stigmod.service;

import net.stigmod.domain.node.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

public class StigmodUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    private final User user;

    public StigmodUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        User.SecurityRole[] roles = user.getRole();
        if (roles == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return Arrays.<GrantedAuthority>asList(roles);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getMail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

@@@ StigmodUserDetailsService.java @@@

```
package net.stigmod.service;

import net.stigmod.domain.node.User;
import net.stigmod.repository.node.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class StigmodUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public StigmodUserDetailsService() {}

    public StigmodUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public StigmodUserDetails loadUserByUsername(String mail) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        final User user = userRepository.findByMail(mail);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found: " + mail);
        }
        return new StigmodUserDetails(user);
    }

    public User getUserFromSession() {
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof StigmodUserDetails) {
            StigmodUserDetails userDetails = (StigmodUserDetails) principal;
            return userDetails.getUser();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Transactional
    public User register(String mail, String password, String passwordRepeat) {
        User found = userRepository.findByMail(mail);
        if (found != null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Email already taken: " + mail);
        }
        if (password == null || password.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No password provided.");
        }
        if (passwordRepeat == null || passwordRepeat.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No password-repeat provided.");
        }
        if (!password.equals(passwordRepeat)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Passwords provided do not equal.");
        }
        User user = userRepository.save(new User(mail, password, User.SecurityRole.ROLE_USER));
        setUserInSession(user);
        return user;
    }

    void setUserInSession(User user) {
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        StigmodUserDetails userDetails = new StigmodUserDetails(user);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, user.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
        context.setAuthentication(authentication);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the problem is somehow related to the fact that you mix Class Based configuration with XML based.

Comment: The problem should be the `@Autowired` on `UserRepository`, he try to instantiate an interface

Comment: @Iffo It seems to be a Spring-data trick to `@Autowired` a field on an interface that without an explicit implementation. I learned that from [Spring-data guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/), right?

Comment: @Iffo I tried to remove the `@Repository` annotation from `UserRepository`, same error remains.

Comment: @Ralph I updated the beginning of my question, adding some background information of this project. I build my project from an example. The example also used a mixed configuration style, and it works fine.